# Pig Latin converter c++ function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am in the process of developing a program that converts someones name into pig latin, my code is compiling and is very close to working however I have been given the `main()` and it cannot be edited. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

    void convertToPigLatin(string& name);
    void lowercase(string& name);

    int main()
    {

            string first = "Trevor";
            string last = "Chappel";
            string fullname;
            convertToPigLatin(first);
            convertToPigLatin(last);
            fullname = first + " " + last;
            cout << "Your name in pig latin is: " << fullname << endl;

    }

    void convertToPigLatin(string & name)
    {
        // begins with vowel.
        if (name[0] == 'a' || name[0] == 'e' || name[0] == 'i' || name[0] == 'o' || 
        name[0] == 'u' || name[0] == 'A' || name[0] == 'E' || name[0] == 'I' || name[0] == 'O' || name[0] == 'U')
        {
            // Add "way" to the end.
            name[0] = toupper(name[0]);
            cout << name << "way ";
        }

        // It begins with a consonant. Move it to the end and add "ay"
        else
        {
            name[0] = tolower(name[0]);
            name += name[0];
            name.erase(0, 1);
            name[0] = toupper(name[0]);

            cout << name << "ay ";
        }
    }

    void lowercase(string& name)
    {
        int i = 1;
        while (name[i] != '\0')
        {
            name[i] = tolower(name[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

My output is `Revortay Happelcay Your name in pig latin is: Trevor Chappel`
and the desired output is `Your name in pig latin is: Evortray Appelchay`.
So as you can see it is close. I have spent 4 hours on this and am not getting anywhere.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to append the suffixes (`"way"` and `"ay"`) to the actual string, and not print them out inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

You are using cout incorrectly. cout is an object to access stdout. string::append() is probably the function you want to look up.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
// begins with vowel.
        if (name[0] == 'a' || name[0] == 'e' || name[0] == 'i' || name[0] == 'o' || 
        name[0] == 'u' || name[0] == 'A' || name[0] == 'E' || name[0] == 'I' || name[0] == 'O' || name[0] == 'U')
        {
            // Add "way" to the end.
            name[0] = toupper(name[0]);
            cout << name << "way ";
        }
```

**You use `cout` to print out the name, you dont actually add "way" to the string.**

Also, you can make this way smoother when you do something like this:

```
// checks if the character 'c' is a vowel and returns either true of false
bool is_vowel(char c) 
{
    c = tolower(c);
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
}

// returns a new pig-latin string 
string getPigLatinName(string name)
{
    if(is_vowel(name[0]))
    {
        return name.append("way");
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: implement me yourself
    }
}
```

So you can use that like this:

```
string name("albert"); // now name == "albert"
name = getPigLatinName(name); // now name == "albertway"
```